# Limiting post sql results

Tags: php, mysql, search-engine

Im building a search engine from scratch.

- It scans many different tables in multiple databases.
- It searches through only the specified columns.
- The search words are `explode()`'ed case of multiple words search
- It iterates with a `foreach` through the tables.

I'm having trouble structuring the code base with `LIMIT`. I want it to show only `DISTINCT`.

For example if I search `Joe Schmoe` my code will search for `first = joe` and then for `last = schmoe`, and it will display a result for each search. But I want it to display only one result for the two searches.

```
<?php

echo "<h1>Search Results</h1>";

echo "<table style='width: 100%;'>";

$a = $_GET["q"];

$b = explode(" ", $a);

include 'db_connect3.php';

mysql_select_db("db440035579", $con);

foreach($b as $c){
$sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE first LIKE '%$c%' || last LIKE '%$c%'";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<a href='applications.php?act=search&uid=$row[7]'>$row[5], $row[4]</a>";
  }
}


mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Have you explored 'Full Text Search' options with different DBs?  [For example](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-natural-language.html).  Does this look enticing?  `SELECT id, MATCH (title,body) AGAINST ('Tutorial') FROM articles;`

Comment: Why does this get upvoted? Your code will only search for the last word used, you are very vulnerable for injections, and you are still using mysql_* functions instead of PDO's or mysqli's prepared statements. + there is tons of information if you just research a little.

Comment: Im aware im using the mysql functions, this was because the site originated in the old style and im against a deadline to finish for my company.  When it is functional and launched I will work on the upgrade to PDO and mysqli.. In regards to the other information it is vunerable to injection however you only saw the little part, im using 3 different db and about 30 tables, with limited colums in each table, with specifics of on the items searched with a pulldown from a keywords db.  it gets complicated, that is why icould nt find exactly what i needed.

Answer (score 0):

First of all http://bobby-tables.com/

Secondly, plugging in `PDO` takes only a few lines of code.

Thirdly, FULL TEXT SEARCH is much better.

**And finally:**

Use a array microcaching. I assume `$row[0]` is the `user.id`. That way you only get one item per `ID`

```
$cache = array();    
foreach($b as $c){
    $sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE first LIKE '%$c%' || last LIKE '%$c%'";

    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $cache[$row[0]] = $row;
    }
}
foreach($cache as $row){
    echo "<a href='applications.php?act=search&uid=$row[7]'>$row[5], $row[4]</a>";
}
```